# From --to as a subject

Tags: grammar

From 300 to 500 million people are affected by malaria.
Can I use 'from ---to ---'' as a subject?
Please explain it to me.

Comment: No, not just "300 to 500". The preposition phrase "from 300 to 500 million people" is the subject.

Comment: No. The subject of a sentence will never be in a prepositional phrase. Since "people" is the subject, it is not included in the prepositional phrase, "from 300 to 500 million".

Comment: @BuffyOverflow The subject is not **in** the preposition phrase. The subject **is** the preposition phrase.

Comment: Of course preposition phrases can be subjects, e.g "After the Easter vacation would be a good time for me".

Comment: @BillJ Surely *people* is not the complement of *from*? I would take *from 300 to 500* as a quantificational PP modifying the head, *people*.

Comment: I didn't say it was.The "NP 300 to 500 million people" is the complement of "from". In the NP, 300 to 500 million is a DP with "people" as head.

Comment: @BillJ, the subject of your sentence is "time" and that noun is not part of a prepositional phrase. The other nouns are preceded by prepositions, e.g.: "after" and "for" and therefore are not the subject.

Comment: @BillJ Consult *CGEL*, p.646, *PPs with quantificational complements*. The examples at [35 i.] are described as functioning "as determiners in the bracketed NPs" and distinguished from the PPs in [35 ii.] which act as if they were NPs.

Comment: @BuffyOverflow No, "good time" is a predicative complement of "be".

Comment: @BillJ, time is a noun, and "good" is an adjective to describe that noun.

Comment: @StoneyB That's what I said! "300 to 500 million" is a DP inside the NP "300 to 500 million people".

Comment: @BillJ If you follow *CGEL* (and in this instance I do), it is the PP *From 300 to 500* which is the DP. *People*, not *from*, is the head of the NP. Look at example [35 i. b.] *She wrote between forty and fifty novels*, where *between forty and fifty* is the PP acting as DP and [*between forty and fifty **novels***] is identified as the NP.

Comment: @BuffyOverflow "a good time for me" is an NP as predicative complement of "be" in its ascriptive sense. Note that it is reversible "A good time for me would be after the Easter vacation".

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, of course, I finally looked at p646! The determiner includes the prep in this kind of construction, so the determiner here is the PP "from 300 to 500 million" inside the NP subject "from 300 to 500 million people".

Comment: @StoneyB Will you tell BuffyOverflow or shall I?

Comment: @BillJ I'm at work, so why don't you.

Answer (score 1):

To be used as a subject, you need to include the noun: "From x to x million *people*...".

While this appears to be a prepositional phrase, it is considered a noun phrase since it contains a numerical phrase. The preposition "from", in this case, is deemed to be part of the determiner. Regardless, the phrase can be the subject, just be sure to include the noun.

Comment: A preposition phrase *can* be a subject: *[From New York to Boston] was the route he followed every week.*

Comment: @StoneyB, the subject in that sentence is "he". He followed the route. "From New York to Boston was the route" is the prepositional phrase. This may help: http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/subject-of-a-sentence.html

Comment: I must differ: *he followed* is a reduced relative clause equivalent to *which he followed*, and modifies *the route*.  *the route [which] he followed* is the PC of the verb *was*, and its subject is *From New York to Boston*.

Comment: A preposition phrase can (and does here) serve as the subject of a sentence. 10 examples are [**here.**](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/functioning_as_a_noun_examples/97/)

Comment: @StoneyB and P.E. Dant, we each seem to have sources that conflict on the allowance of a PP being the subject. Do you mind if I ask if you speak UK English? I speak American English and wonder if that could be a factor here.

Comment: @BuffyOverflow I'm a US speaker. ... Your source doesn't say that a PP cannot be a subject; it says the subject cannot be *inside* a PP. This is not literally true, since an entire clause, including its subject, can be the object of a preposition; but it is true that the object of a preposition cannot be the subject of the clause within which the PP is embedded.

Comment: I have never seen a source which claims that a preposition phrase cannot function as a noun, in any geographic location. If Elizabeth makes that claim (which I don't see at the link you provided) then she is wrong, and the revolution has failed.

Comment: @P.E.Dant She doesn't make that claim; the claim she makes is that "The subject of a sentence will never be **in** a preposition phrase". The PP itself may act as subject of its superordinate clause, but the object of the PP does not.

Comment: @StoneyB You overlooked my parenthetical.

Comment: @P.E. Dant, you are correct and I stand corrected. I apologize if my error has caused anyone confusion. Thank you for your diligence in this.

Comment: The OP is the important person here!

Comment: @P.E. Dant, agreed, therefore I corrected my answer to reflect your kind diligence in helping me see my error.

Comment: @BuffyOverflow Erm, I hate to tell you this but "From 300 to 500 million people" is actually a noun phrase, not a preposition phrase. Having consulted the 'oracle', in constructions like this where a PP contains a numeral phrase, the preposition is, exceptionally, deemed to be part of the determiner. So although the subject is still "From 300 to 500 million people", it is in fact a noun phrase, not a preposition phrase. Nevertheless, preposition phrases can in general function as subject if they denote places or times. My apologies for the confusion; I overlooked a 'special' rule of grammar.

Comment: @BillJ, no worries, I appreciate you looking into that. Can the noun phrase still be a subject?

Comment: Yes, indeed it can. Because the sequence "From 300 to 500 million people" is in fact a noun phrase, it can function as a subject just like any other noun phrase. The 'head' of the noun phrase is "people" and the sequence "from 300 to 500 million" is the determiner. The reason it's a 'special' construction is purely because of the numeral phrase "300 to 500 million". In other 'normal' constructions, the preposition would be external to the determiner. Incidentally, a good example of a preposition phrase as subject is "**Under the mat** is the place where we used to leave the key for the boys"

Comment: Excellent. I'll update my answer to include this information. I want to make sure OP has the correct information.

Comment: @BillJ So it is the _numeral phrase_ that the oracle deems worthy of this special treatment? It makes sense now I think of it, unlike some of what the oracle comes up with. That _is_ a PP (from N to N) serving as the determiner, though, isn't it?